# Execute method after certain period of time

Tags: java, methods, time, delay

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\myPC\\Desktop\\selenium\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com/");

    WebElement sbut = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tsf\"]/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[2]"));

    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sbut.click();
                }
            },
            5000
    );

}
```

I have the following code and I'm trying yo click a button after a certain amount of time, but whenever I run my code, nothing happens. Like the timer does not want to execute the method. Why is this happening?

And when I put `sbut.click();` under the `WebElement`, it works.

Thanks id advance

Comment: First check whether your task is even executed. Do so by placing a `System.out.println("Executing")` inside the `run` method. If you see the print, it got executed. Then call back.

Comment: Very important, note that `WebElement`s in `Selenium` are objects that should never be stored and accessed after some time. Browser tend to re-create sites regularly and it very very frequently happens that *Selenium elements* then **stale** and can't be used anymore. Elements should thus be accessed immediately after they are fetched. So instead you might want to move the creation of `sbut` inside the task.